# Ford Focus 2 alternator not chargin battery

Tags: ford, alternator, focus, belt

I own a Ford Focus 2.0L Duratec(European version).
Since some days ago I noticed a slight noise, like a very little vacuum cleaner and the alternator is not charging, for some moments I have 13.2V, but mostly I have below 12V.
The noise change with the engine RPM.
Can be the belt?
I didn't notice any raise in the temperature of the engine and the noise is very low.

Comment: Is the charging malfunction light present or not? Where and how do you measure the voltage?

Comment: No, there's not signal at all. I measured the voltage with the car tracker device. I already repaired this. It was the diode board, change a installed a new one. Thanks anyway.